# PySide6: JSONDecoderError during run empty pyproject

Tags: python, qt, qml, qtquick2

I created an empty Qt Quick Application on Qt 6.5.2 in Qt Creator, then I edit .pyproject as follows:

```json
{
    "files": [
        "main.py",
        "main.qml"
    ],
    "qmlImportPath": [
        "path/to/my/qml/directory"
    ]
}
```

After building the project, an exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Qt Project\untitled\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\scripts\project.py", line 240, in <module>
    project = Project(project_file)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Qt Project\untitled\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\scripts\project.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.project = ProjectData(project_file=project_file)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Qt Project\untitled\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\scripts\project\project_data.py", line 30, in __init__
    pyproject = json.load(pyf)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\envs\ml\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\envs\ml\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\envs\ml\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\envs\ml\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And when I use Ctrl+z undo what I haved editted, the exception is still consistent.

Comment: How did you edit your project?  Does your editor add a BOM to the file?

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried reducing the involved code to a [mcve]? Have you searched for the error message to gain some understanding what could cause it?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt My problem is I cannot run my project successfully. I can't provide  minimal reproducible example, because my code is totally same as defaultly created code. With the totally same code/files, version before editted can work but latter can't. I also tried to search my error meesaage on Internet, but no one met the similar problem.

Comment: @ewokx I edited file in qt creator, and I did add a BOM to the file.

Comment: So, you searched the internet? I'd say you need to practice more: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JSONDecodeError%3A+Expecting+value%3A+line+1+column+1+%28char+0%29

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the heads up, searching on stackoverflow is probably more effective than searching on google or bing :). By the way, when I mentioned "no one had a similar problem" I meant that no one had the same problem when trying to build pyproject. Most of the questions you provide are talking about https or network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ewokx's help in comment, I have solved my problem now.

PySide6 tool kit is based on parsing .pyproject which is a json file. However, in my case, after I edited .pyproject, The editor implicitly added BOM to the front of file, which means JSONDecoder could no longer identify this file as a raw json file.

After removing the BOM, everything works fine.